# Qt QSql class error

Tags: sql, qt, compiler-errors, sqlconnection

I'm trying to create a connection to a database in Qt 5.0
but I get these errors!

```
In function `_tcf_0':
error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QSqlDatabaseD1Ev'
error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QSqlDatabase11addDatabaseERK7QStringS2_'
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I copied the Help's sample code and still got the same error :

```
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase> 
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

Is this a Qt bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added sql to QT variable in you pro file like this:

```
QT += core gui sql
```

?